# ¿Cómo eliminar palabras repetidas de un arreglo?

Tags: java, array, archivo, arraylist

Buen día comunidad espero me puedan ayudar, lo que sucede es que estoy leyendo un archivo texto las palabras del archivo las guardo en un arreglo pero necesito que las palabras repetidas se eliminen. Mi archivo de texto contiene lo siguienete:

```
inicio 

program
 
stmtlist
 
stmtlist
 
stmt 

stmt
 
stmt
 
stmt
 
idlist
 
idfinal
 
idfinal
```

Llevo el siguiente codigo:

```
    public void ladoIzquierdo(String[] arc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arc.length - 1; i++) {
            NTerminales = new String[arc[0].length()];
            NTerminales[i] = arc[0];
        }
        System.out.println(Repetido(NTerminales));
    }
```

en el arreglo de arc guardo lo que se esta leyendo del archivo texto y en el arreglo de `NTerminales` guardo exactamente lo mismo que en arc lo que busco es que en `NTerminales` solo contenga una vez cada palabra leida del archivo de texto es decir solo una vez program, solo una vez stmtlist  y asi para cada palabra.

Comment: Si solo puedo usar arrays

Answer (score 1):

Haces dos **ciclos for anidados** y vas recorriendo el **arreglo** n veces(parecido al método de ordenamiento burbuja). El **ciclo for exterior** coge un elemento del arreglo y en el **ciclo for interior** se recorre el arreglo preguntando si algún elemento del **arreglo[j]** es igual al **arreglo[i]**, de ser iguales quiere decir que hay un duplicado, por tanto borras ese elemento poniéndolo vacío(""):

```
public void EliminarRepetidos(String[] arreglo) 
{
   for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++)
   {
      for(int j = i + 1; j < arreglo.length; j++)
      {
         if(i != j)
         {
            if(arreglo[i] == arreglo[j])
            {
               arreglo[j] = "";
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Una vez que sales de ese método para mostrar el arreglo sin duplicados harías:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++)
{
   if(arreglo[i] != "")
   {
      //Imprimes el elemento
   } 
}
```

Es decir recorres el arreglo ya sin duplicados y preguntas si la posición no está vacía, de no estarlo imprimes el elemento del arreglo en esa posición.

Si quieres hacerlo  de una manera más corta usa la estructura **HashSet** la cual no admite datos duplicados:

```
Set<String> NoDuplicados = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arreglo));
```

En este ejemplo se construye un **HashSet** de **string** el cual recibe como parámetro una lista, por lo que debes transformar tu arreglo a un tipo **List**. Para convertir el arreglo a lista se usa la instrucción:

```
Arrays.asList(arreglo)
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no puedo utilizar ArrayList solo arreglos

Comment: Pero eso no lo habias dicho

Comment: Tienes toda la razón omiti decir eso.

Comment: @EmmanuelHerrera, revisa lo nuevo que puse y dime si te sirvió

Comment: Intente hacer lo de los ciclos anidados y no me funciono estoy a por probar  el HashSet si me funciono te aviso y de antemano gracias

Comment: @EmmanuelHerrera, pq no te funciono, que error te dio, dime q te paso?

Comment: @EmmanuelHerrera, acabe de probar el codigo y funciona bien, que fue lo que hiciste?

Comment: @EmmanuelHerrera, el codigo si funciona socio, el codigo lo que hace es eliminar los elementos repetidos del arreglo, asi q revisa bien

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Map<Character, Integer> guardaValoresCharRepetidos(char[] caracteres)
{
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (char keyCaracter: caracteres) {
        map.put(keyCaracter, map.getOrDefault(keyCaracter, 0) + 1);
    }

    return map;
}

private static int cuentaRepetidos(Map<Character, Integer> map, char caracter) {
    return map.get(caracter);
}

private static Set<String> eliminaDuplicados(char[] caracteres){
    Set<String> duplicados = new HashSet<String>();

    for(int i=1; i <= (caracteres.length -1); i++ ) {
        duplicados.add(String.valueOf(caracteres[i]));
                    
     }
    return duplicados;
}



public static void resultadoCuentaCaracteres() {
    String str = "ABAACBDDRRRR";
     
    Map<Character, Integer> map = guardaValoresCharRepetidos(str.toCharArray());
    
    char[] caracteres = str.toCharArray();
    
    Set<String> duplicados =eliminaDuplicados(caracteres);
    
    for(String indexDuplicado :duplicados) {
    
    try {
        
    char caracter =indexDuplicado.charAt(indexDuplicado.length() -1);
    
    System.out.println("Caracter " + caracter + " se repite " +  cuentaRepetidos(map,  caracter) + " veces.");
    }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        
        System.out.print(ex);
        
    }
 


}
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).