# Crea una función que dada una matriz de valores enteros retorne otra matriz con los valores de la matriz original sin duplicados

Tags: java

Estoy repasando el tema de arrays por medio de funcionalidades, antes de empezar con colecciones. Pero ando un poco perdido con este ejercicio. A ver si me podeis ayudar.
El ejercicio me pide devolver una matriz, no modificarla, en la que solo aparezca por pantalla los valores de los indices que no se repitan. Para ello tengo dos funciones como podeis ver en el codigo. Una que valida si se repite algún valor o no. Si se repite, solo presentará en pantalla los valores sin tener en cuenta los valores repetidos.

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[]m=new int[]{5,1,1,9,8,7,8,10};
    boolean respuesta=false;
    int[]r;
    respuesta=in(m,8,8);
    if(respuesta==true) {
        r=noDuplicado(m);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
    
}

static boolean in( int[] array, int value, int count ) {
    boolean respuesta=false;
    int contador=count;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i]==value) {
            count++;
        }
        respuesta=true;
    }
    return respuesta;
}

static int[]noDuplicado(int[]matriz){
    int[]copia=Arrays.copyOf(matriz, matriz.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < copia.length; i++) {
        if(copia[i]==copia[i+1]){
        copia[i]=copia[i+1];    
        }
        
    }
    
    return copia;
}
```

`

Comment: El método `in` devuelve `true` en cuanto encuentras un valor igual... pero es obvio que siempre vas a tener UN valor igual, necesitas devolver true si encuentras DOS, imagino, no? Para eso deberías devolver `count > 1`, porque además, si no, la variable `count` no tiene sentido ahí puesto que solo la incrementas, nunca la usas para nada realmente. En cuanto al método `noDuplicado`... qué se supone que quieres hacer en el `if` de dentro del for? Porque no le veo sentido si lo que intentas es crear un array sin duplicados. Tampoco veo mucho sentido a lo que haces en el main, podrías explicarlo?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464589/c%c3%b3mo-eliminar-palabras-repetidas-de-un-arreglo/464617#464617  entra aqui

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por contestar, la función in tiene que verificar si tiene algún valor repetido. El tema es que me propusieron usar tres parámetros ( la matriz, el valor y el count) el count  supuse que valdria para contar los valores repetidos y a la hora de invocar a la funcion noDuplicar darle a la nueva matriz (lenght -count) pero no sé muy bien como implementarlo

Comment: Por otra, en la matriz noDuplicar, lo que he intentado implementar es que al iterar, si encuentra un valor duplicado que se quede solo con uno de esos valores.

Comment: Y en el main, a la hora de invocar la función in, al usar tres parámetros he tenido que meter esos tres datos y no sabía muy bien..

Comment: gracias @Japv por el enlace. De todos modos este metodo es un void, yo lo que quería implementar con el metodo que static int era el cambiar la matriz si alterar la original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo quieres mostrar los valores no repetidos del vector `m` que declaras.

Cuando ya conoces los valores de tu vector, no es necesario realizar

```
int[]m=new int[]{5,1,1,9,8,7,8,10};
```

Declaras de la siguiente forma

```
int[]m={5,1,1,9,8,7,8,10};
```

El método `in` es innecesario ya que no realiza nada.
En el método `noDuplicado` declaras un nuevo vector y copias el vector que recibes por parámetro lo cual es innecesario, puedes usar el mismo vector que recibes por parámetro.

Te dejo una solución de tu ejercicio.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int m[]={5,1,1,9,8,7,8,10};        
        m=noDuplicado(m);       
        
        //mostramos los valores no duplicados
       for (int k=0;k<=m.length-1;k++){
            if(m[k]!=0){
                    System.out.println( m[k]);
            }
       }
}    

static int[] noDuplicado(int[]matriz){ 
        for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<matriz.length-1;j++){
                if(i!=j){
                    if(matriz[i]==matriz[j]){
                            // cambiamos el valor del índice repetido a 0
                            matriz[i]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
        return matriz;
}
```

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por contestar, la función in tiene que verificar si tiene algún valor repetido. El tema es que me propusieron usar tres parámetros ( la matriz, el valor y el count) el count supuse que valdria para contar los valores repetidos y a la hora de invocar a la funcion noDuplicar darle a la nueva matriz (lenght -count) pero no sé muy bien como implementarlo. El tema es que es un vector muy pequeño y la verificación podría sobrar.. Pero si fuese muy grande la matriz es para ahorrarse hacer la pasada y quitar los valores duplicados

Answer (score 0):

Al final el código termino así, dado que hay limitaciones a la hora de implementar en un array estático:

```
package src;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ejercicio22 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[]m=new int[]{5,1,1,9,8,7,8,10};
    System.out.println(length_no_dupl(m));
    int[]r = noDuplicado( m );
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}

/**
 * Devuelve una matriz sin duplicados.
 * @param matriz Matriz de origen
 * @return Matriz de destino
 */
    static int[] noDuplicado(int[]matriz){ 
        int[] resultado = new int[length_no_dupl(matriz)];
        int valor; 
        int indx_origen = 0; 
        int indx_destino = 0; 
        for( indx_origen = 0; indx_origen < matriz.length; indx_origen++) {
            valor = matriz[indx_origen];
            if ( !in(resultado, valor, indx_destino )) {
                resultado[indx_destino] = valor; 
                indx_destino++; 
            }
        }
        return resultado; 
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el nº de valores sin duplicados presentes en una matriz
     * @param array Matriz a examinar
     * @return Cantidad de valores sin duplicas
     */
    static int length_no_dupl( int[] array ) {
        int longitud = 0; 
        int valor; 
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            valor = array[i];
            if ( !in( array, valor, i))
                longitud++; 
        }
        return longitud; 
    }
    
    /**
     * Retorna un valor lógico indicando si el valor dado está contenido en la matriz en la seccion comprendida por los primeros valores indicados
     * @param array Matriz a examinar
     * @param value Valor a buscar
     * @param count Longitud de la seccion a comprobar
     * @return TRUE si el valor está contenido FALSE si no.
     */
    static boolean in( int[] array, int value, int count ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if ( array[i] == value) 
                return true; 
        }
        return false; 
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    static int foo( int a, int b ) {
        return 0; 
    }
    }
```