# ¿Cómo eliminar palabras repetidas en una matriz?

Tags: c

Tengo problemas al querer eliminar palabras repetidas, ya que mi código solo funciona con un una palabra repetida, pero si se ingresan mas de 2 no las elimina.

#### Entrada

[image: input]

#### Salida

[image: output]

Y Aqui mi codigo.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
       int n;
       printf("¿Cuantos palabras desea 
       ingresar? ");
       scanf("%d", &n);
       char palabras[n][1000];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
          printf("Ingrese la palabra 
          %d: ", i + 1);
          scanf("%s", &palabras[i]);
       }
       int salvar;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
          for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
          {
              if (strcmp(palabras[0], 
              palabras[j]) == 0)
              {
                  salvar = j;
                  for (int j = salvar;             
                  j < n; j++)
                  {
                     
                    strcpy(palabras[j], palabras[j + 1]);
                  }
                  n = n - 1;
                  salvar = j - 2;
              }
          }
      }
      printf("\nPalabras sin 
      repetir:\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          printf("%s\n", palabras[i]);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar!!

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464589/c%c3%b3mo-eliminar-palabras-repetidas-de-un-arreglo/464617#464617, entra aqui, el codigo esta en Java, pero es el mismo problema que tienes, si la respuesta te es util por favor dale un voto y si tienes dudas me avisas

Comment: @Japv java es un lenguaje de altisimo nivel, puede comparar strings de forma demasiado sencilla lo cual no explica ni de cerca todos los procesos que ocurren por detras antes de procesar el array. Aca en C hay que hacer todo de 0 por eso su ejercicio tiene trasfondo. Y no equivale a lo mismo

Comment: En su momento me vi interesado por una estructura similar a un HashSet, o así proveniente de Java o C#, lo que hacen es que no pueda haber elementos repetidos. Me encontré con `unordered_set` por si les interesa el dato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código está casi bien y funciona, con una corrección, aunque no sea óptimo. Error que tienes está en la comparación de las palabras, `if (strcmp(palabras[0],palabras[j]) == 0)`, que siempre comparas respecto a la primera solamente *palabras[**0**]*.

Este es el código corregido y formateado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   int n;
   printf("¿Cuantos palabras desea ingresar? ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   char palabras[n][1000];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("\nIngrese la palabra %d: ", i + 1);
      scanf("%s", &palabras[i]);
   }
   
   int salvar;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
          if (strcmp(palabras[i], palabras[j]) == 0) {
              salvar = j;
              for (int j = salvar; j < n; j++) {
                strcpy(palabras[j], palabras[j + 1]);
              }
              n = n - 1;
              salvar = j - 2;
          }
      }
  }
  printf("\nPalabras sin repetir:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", palabras[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de entrada/salida del programa:

> ¿Cuantos palabras desea ingresar? 8
> Ingrese la palabra 1: Plástico
> Ingrese la palabra 2: Papel
> Ingrese la palabra 3: Metal
> Ingrese la palabra 4: Plastico
> Ingrese la palabra 5: Papel
> Ingrese la palabra 6: Aire
> Ingrese la palabra 7: Agua
> Ingrese la palabra 8: Agua
> Palabras sin repetir:
> Plástico
> Papel
> Metal
> Aire
> Agua